# Xamarin.Forms build fails

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Accidently I deleted the **bin** folder in my xamarin.forms android application


I get following error when I build the project, help.

[image]

Comment: If you have not deleted anything from the project references, start clean building your application on dependency basis and it should work, what I basically mean here is build PCL/.Net Standard first then the native projects

Answer (score 0):

If you just delete the bin folder like this screenshot.
[image]

It does not matter, you can click the `Build` tab, then select the `clean solution` like this screenshot.
[image]

Then click the `Build solution` in the `Build` tab.

It will generate `bin` folder again.
[image]

Comment: Can you try to remove this Nuget packages, then re-add them?